# What does =" " do in excel-vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

What would this do?

```
If Dir(path) = " " Then  
    path = " "
```

Comment: How a typo question is upvoted is beyond me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an unnecessary space between the quotes

What the code is basically trying to do is to check if the relevant file, directory, or folder exists. See this example which checks if a file exists or not.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim sPath As String

    sPath = "C:\Temp\MyFile.xls"

    If Dir(sPath) = "" Then
        MsgBox "File not found"
    Else
        MsgBox "File found"
    End If
End Sub
```

More on `DIR` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. But what would sPath = "" do?

Comment: I guess the code that you gave is a part of a bigger code. What I am assuming is that if a particular File or directory is not found then it is resetting the `path` variable to nothing.

Comment: Side comment: I use `folderExists = ((GetAttr(parPath) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory)` instead...

Comment: @assylias: That is mentioned in the msdn link that I have given above :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Ha indeed - I was wondering why I was doing that instead of the standard `If Dir() = ""` thingy! Thanks.

Comment: +1 - although `vbNullstring` is a little prettier :)